# Can' t print Greek characters (1253 or 737) with citizen ct-s651ii embed font with Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, posprinter

I 'm trying to print some text with Greek and Latin characters to a citizen ct-s651ii thermal pos printer using the embedded Font-A font with Delphi 10.3 Rio.

It prints the latin characters but instead of the Greek characters it prints dots (".").

I have set with the citizen pos printer utility the code page to "Space page user fonts" and i have register the wpc1253.cgh font (also tried the pc737.cgh).

I'm not sending esc commands.

I use this code:

```
Printer.BeginDoc;
Printer.Canvas.Font.Name := 'FontA11 [255]';
Printer.Canvas.TextOut(0,0, 'ΑΒΓΔΕ');
Printer.EndDoc;
```

From the pos printer utility the "test print" function prints some code pages and it prints the "user define Font-A" code page with the Greek characters without problem.

I'm using the same method and code with an Epson tm-t88v printer without a problem.

Is the citizen printer handling different the textout commands or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How is the code page defined in Font-A? Do you provide any Unicode information?

Comment: Don't know that. The pos utility doesn't provide much information. I import the code page file "wpc1253-1224.cgh" (included with the utility) and hit register button. I also set the code page setting to "space page user fonts". From the pos utility the "test print" prints it without problem. You can read the manual of the utility that is included to this link [pos_utility](https://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/en/printer/download/utility/?p=CT-S601_II_Re-stick_Liner-free)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://www.citizen-systems.com/en/products/printer/pos/ct-s651ii/), this printer supports the following code pages:     Alphanumeric, International characters, Katakana, Thai code18, WPC1252, 437, 850, 852, 857, 858, 860, 863, 864, 865 and 866

Locate the characters you want to print in one of those code pages and select it.

If this doesn't work, you can always print the ticket to a bitmap and then print the bitmap. Using this method, you can use any font supported by Windows, regardless of what the printer supports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need to print with the embedded font.
It doesn't mention it at the documentation but you can upload a code page (included with the pos utility) and register it to the printer with the citizen pos printer utility [link](https://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/en/printer/download/utility/?p=CT-S601_II_Re-stick_Liner-free)
I did it and the test print prints it without a problem.